# MBProgessHUD - When voiceover is on i want the focus to shift to the spinning wheel and not on the background elements

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover, mbprogresshud

I'm using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) library to show an activity indicator while there is a backend call. When i have the voiceover switched on the control is still within the background elements and not on the activity indicator view. How do i bring the voiceover control to the Activity indicator until its completed?

Answer (score 0):

self.hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, self.hud);
self.hud.accessibilityViewIsModal = YES;

This code snippet will make the voiceover to focus on the activity indicator and we can switch to the label by using the swipe control.